# Can't execute a function once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a script that counts to a number when i scroll to an element, but i want the script to fire only one time, i tried by setting the variable `execute` to false , after the script is fired. but it still counting over and over, (i explained the situation more in the commented code)

```js
$(function() {
    var oTop = $('.stats').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        if( pTop > oTop ){
              start_count();
        }
    });
});

function start_count(){

var executed = false; // <= variable to false.

if (!executed){ // <= make sure it didn't executed before.

    $('.stats h1').countTo({
      onComplete: function() {
        var elementToPrepend = '<span style="margin-left:4px;">+</span>';
        $(elementToPrepend).hide().appendTo(this).fadeIn();

      }
    });
    
    executed = true; // <= the count() function already executed
    
}

}
```

```css
.empty-space{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countto/1.2.0/jquery.countTo.js"></script>

<div class="empty-space">
scroll down...
</div>

<div class="stats">
<h1 data-from="200" data-to="2000" data-speed="1750" data-refresh-interval="50">200</h1>
</div>

<div class="empty-space">

</div>
```

As you can see if you reach the counter element it keeps counting again and again, is there any way to fix that and make it run once? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `executed` is scoped to low.  it is destroyed after the method ends.

Comment: aka everytime you call `start_count` you redefine `executed`

Comment: You should define it outside the function, so it won't get reset each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
        var oTop = $('.stats').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
        $(window).scroll(function(){

            var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
            if( pTop > oTop ){
                  start_count();
            }
        });
    });
     var executed = false; // <= variable to false.

    function start_count(){

   

    if (!executed){ // <= make sure it didn't executed before.

        $('.stats h1').countTo({
          onComplete: function() {
            var elementToPrepend = '<span style="margin-left:4px;">+</span>';
            $(elementToPrepend).hide().appendTo(this).fadeIn();

          }
        });
        
        executed = true; // <= the count() function already executed
        
    }

    }
```

```css
.empty-space{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countto/1.2.0/jquery.countTo.js"></script>

<div class="empty-space">
scroll down...
</div>

<div class="stats">
<h1 data-from="200" data-to="2000" data-speed="1750" data-refresh-interval="50">200</h1>
</div>

<div class="empty-space">

</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if you have any concern

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code is doing what you think.

```
var executed = false; // <= variable to false.

if (!executed){ // <= make sure it didn't executed before.
```

this will always run because executed is a set variable.

you want to remove the variable before the check.
If you set the variable without the var declaration it can be deleted and checked.

```
executed = false
if (!executed) {} returns true

delete executed 
if (!executed) {} returns false
```

when you declare a variable with var it cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime the function is executed, `executed=false`, therefore, `!executed==true`.
You must declare the variable outside of the function, like this:

```
var executed = false; // <= variable to false.

function start_count(){

if (!executed){ // <= make sure it didn't executed before.

$('.stats h1').countTo({
  onComplete: function() {
    var elementToPrepend = '<span style="margin-left:4px;">+</span>';
    $(elementToPrepend).hide().appendTo(this).fadeIn();

  }
});

executed = true; // <= the count() function already executed
// it will remain true until an external function changes it

}
}
```

And a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/30w9kbfj/